# Using Lexical Filtering of Azure Table on range of RowKey values

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Problem: no results are returned.

I'm using the following code to get a range of objects from a partition with only 100 or so rows:

```
var rangeQuery = new TableQuery<StorageEntity>().Where(
                TableQuery.CombineFilters(
                    TableQuery.CombineFilters(
                        TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, partitionKey),
                        TableOperators.And,
                        TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, from)
                    ),
                    TableOperators.And,
                    TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.LessThanOrEqual, to)
                )
            );

            var results = table.ExecuteQuery(rangeQuery);
foreach (StorageEntity entity in results)
            {
                storageEntities.Add(entity);
            }
```

NOTE: it doesn't seem to matter how I combine the 3 terms, no results are returned.  An example of one that I am expecting is this (partitionKey, rowKey):

"10005678", "PL7NR_201503170900"

The ranged filter code generates this expression:

> ((PartitionKey eq '10005678') and (RowKey ge 'PL7NR_201503150000'))
>   and (RowKey lt 'PL7NR_201504082359')

But I have also tried this (which is my preferred approach for performance reasons, i.e. partition scan):

> (PartitionKey eq '10005678') and ((RowKey ge 'PL7NR_201503150000') and
>   (RowKey lt 'PL7NR_201504082359'))

My understanding is that the Table storage performs a lexical search and that these row keys should therefore encompass a range that includes a row with the following keys:

"10005678", "PL7NR_201503170900"

Is there something fundamentally wrong with my understanding?

Thanks for looking at this.

UPDATE: question updated thanks to Gaurav's answer.  The code above implicitly handles continuation tokens (i.e. the foreach loop) and there are only 100 or so items in the partition, so I do not see the continuation tokens as being an issue.

I have tried removing the underscores ('_') from the key and even tried moving the prefix from the rowKey and adding it as a suffix to the partitionKey.

> NOTE: This is all running on my local machine using storage emulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`Query Timeout and Pagination`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135718.aspx):

> A query against the Table service may return a maximum of 1,000 items
>   at one time and may execute for a maximum of five seconds. If the
>   result set contains more than 1,000 items, if the query did not
>   complete within five seconds, or if the query crosses the partition
>   boundary, the response includes headers which provide the developer
>   with continuation tokens to use in order to resume the query at the
>   next item in the result set. Continuation token headers may be
>   returned for a Query Tables operation or a Query Entities operation.

Please check if you're getting back `Continuation Token` in response.

Now coming on to your filter expressions:

> ((PartitionKey eq '10005678') and (RowKey ge 'PL7NR_201503150000'))
>   and (RowKey lt 'PL7NR_201504082359')

This one is definitely doing a **`Full Table Scan`** because `(RowKey lt 'PL7NR_201504082359')` is a clause in itself. For executing of this particular piece, it basically starts from top of the table and find out entities where `RowKey < 'PL7NR_201504082359'` without taking PartitionKey into consideration.

> (PartitionKey eq '10005678') and ((RowKey ge 'PL7NR_201503150000') and
>   (RowKey lt 'PL7NR_201504082359'))

This one is doing a **`Partition Scan`** and you may not get result back if you have too much data in the specified partition or the query takes more than 5 seconds to execute as mentioned above.

So, check if your query is returning any continuation tokens and make use of them to get the next set of entities if no entities are returned.

A few resources that you may find useful:

- **How to get most out of Windows Azure Tables**: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/11/06/how-to-get-most-out-of-windows-azure-tables.aspx
- **Azure Storage Table Design Guide**: Designing Scalable and Performant Tables: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/

Comment: Hi Gaurav, thanks for the detailed answer.  I've updated the question with my response.  In short: I had preferred the partition scan approach (was just trying the other to see if that worked), those link were some of the resources I used to get to this point and I only have 100 items in the partition. Cheers :)

Comment: I just realised I hadn't pasted the foreach loop initially, sorry for that.

Comment: What happens when you query using just the PartitionKey - `(PartitionKey eq '10005678')`? Do you get any data back? Also, will it be possible to upload some sample data somewhere?

Comment: You know, I have just found the server explorer data view (I was stumbling blindly up til now!) and using its query builder I have proven the filter works.  Working back from that, I realised that I had stopped the query processing too early (i.e. before the loop had actually populated the results object properly).  The version of this filter without underscores actually works!  I'm going to test now with underscores back on one side.  I'll let you know what I find and if you add any insights into your answer, I'll select it as the correct one. Cheers.

Comment: OK, so it looks like this is all due to me stopping processing before I'd stepped into the foreach loop body.  Score 1 for late nights with too much coffee.  Thanks for your help, Gaurav.  If you want to add a sanity check for this 'issue' then I'll gladly select your answer.